# Can Scientific Cooperation happen when there's no science to share?

Tags: through-the-ages

The text for the Scientific Cooperation *Pact* reads:

> Every time one of the civilizations plays a technology, it pays 2
>   science less and the other civilization pays 1 science.

What happens if the other civilization has zero accumulated science? Does the tech-playing civilization still get the 2 science discount, or does the pact have no effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually fell into this trap in a game, and was surprised at the rules.  If the other civilization can't pay, you can't develop.

The question was [asked on BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/426786/scientific-cooperation-pact), and the rule that covered it was also discussed there- it's on the last page of the rules, i.e. on pg. 20 under `Scientific Cooperation`:

> If one civilization has no science points, neither civilization can
>   play a technology.